# Allow Visual Foxpro Application to receive HTTP requests

Tags: http, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I am looking for a library or some type of documentation on how to set up a Visual Foxpro app to receive HTTP requests. Any direction in this manner will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is quite a late comment. But if you decide to access VFP data via nodejs and javascript, then it is possible. Search for "Nodejs for Fox Developers" on Geek Gatherings channel on youtube.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start with West Wind Web Connection tool for Visual Foxpro. This will allow you to communicate over HTTP with any web server. They also have a limit free download so that you can test it before you buy it.

[Click here to go to their site](http://www.west-wind.com/webconnection/)

Answer (score 1):

FoxPro itself **cannot** receive HTTP requests.  FoxPro is a database application somewhere between mySQL and Microsoft Access; it doesn't have a server component.

However, you **can** connect to FoxPro from any programmatic web server which can speak OLE DB, ODBC, or even just COM.  [West Wind Web Connection](http://www.west-wind.com/webconnection/) does the latter, and has additional functionality for having FoxPro write output suitable for an HTTP stream.

If you're trying to make a web app using FoxPro, West Wind is a good direction to go.  Conversely, if you just want to reference some data in FoxPro via an HTTP web service, you're better off writing your service in PHP or ASP.NET and having the latter connect as it would to any other database.

Comment: So here is the problem exactly how we are solving. We have a legacy VFP application that we are moving its ability to the cloud. The way I was going to solve it is have a PHP linux stack that sends some type of HTTP request with x parameters that will fire a method inside of the VFP application. Now once the VFP has done its part it will send an XmlHttp request back to the PHP to present to the end user. I just need to figure out how to have the PHP talk to the fox pro which will be on a separate machine. @DougM

Comment: Take a look at the (Visual FoxPro OLE DB provider)[http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839], assuming that your legacy FoxPro application isn't nicely COM-visible.    Not sure you'll be able to make it work on Linux, though, @Krzemienski.

Answer (score 0):

After some thought and research the easiest and quickest way to implement this is going to replicate the same functionality of receiving a HTTP request by having the web layer write to a file that the VFP application will constantly listen in on and when some type of text is present in the file it will execute its function accordingly and make an easy HTTP post back to the web layer with the given data.

Answer (score 0):

VFP comes with an example IIS plugin called FoxIsApi. It allows you to expose VFP objects as urls. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44b055ey(v=vs.80).aspx

Another approach is to expose your VFP application as a COM object and connect to it from NodeJS. NodeJS can than expose your methods as webservices. I've used https://github.com/idobatter/node-win32ole to connect the two.